# Finding the locus of points in complex plane that satisfies a given equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I should find a locus of points $Z$ that satisfy equation: $$Z = a + bt + ct^2 $$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$, $t$ is a real parameter and $\frac{b}{c}$ is real.

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $z=a+c\left(t^2+\dfrac{b}{c}t\right) = a+c\left(\left(t+\dfrac{b}{2c}\right)^2 - \dfrac{b^2}{4c^2} \right)=a+cu$, where $u \in \left[- \dfrac{b^2}{4c^2}, +\infty\right)$.